# Why are there no necessary and sufficient conditions for Pfaffian differential form to be integrable in 2d?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, submanifold

As we know, $\omega(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i(x) dx_i = 0, x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, is [Pfaffian differential form](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Pfaffian_equation) (inexact/exact differential equations). If $d\omega(x) = 0$, then it is [exact differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation); otherwise it's [inexact differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inexact_differential_equation).

For inexact differential equations, maybe there exists an [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) such that $\mu(x) \sum_{i=1}^n a_i(x) dx_i = df(x)$.

For $n\ge3$, there is [Frobenius' theorem](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Pfaffian_equation): $\omega(x)$ has integrating factor $\iff$ $d\omega \wedge \omega = 0$.

Especially, for 3d, $Pdx + Qdy + R dz =0$, the necessary and sufficient conditions that it can has integrating factor is $$P\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial R}{\partial y}\right) + Q\left(\frac{\partial R}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial z}\right) + R\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}\right)  = 0$$

My questions:

1. Why is there no easy criterion to determine $P(x,y) dx + Q(x,y)dy$ has integrating factor?
2. Does inexact differential equation in 2d always have integrating factor, even though it's hard to find in general? Prove or give an example to disprove

Comment: Any nonvanishing $1$-form is always (locally) integrable in $\Bbb R^2$, so (locally) there is always an integrating factor.  There is no local obstruction. (Of course, globally there are always examples in a punctured $\Bbb R^2$, because then we have closed $1$-forms that needn't be exact.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Does it mean inexact differential equation in 2d always exist integrating factor locally, even though it's hard to find in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for any $1$-form $\omega$ so that $\omega$ is nowhere $0$, you can always find an integrating factor (at least locally).

One can see this by thinking about coordinates $(x^1,x^2)$ in which the corresponding *vector field* becomes $\partial/\partial x^1$. But, staying just with differential forms, we know that $d\omega = \eta\wedge\omega$ for some $1$-form $\eta$, and a little bit of calculation shows that we can always change $\eta$ to $\eta'=\eta+\lambda\omega$ so that this form will be closed/exact. Then you can solve $\eta' = -d\log f$ and then
$$d(f\omega) = fd\omega + df\wedge\omega = f\eta'\wedge\omega+df\wedge\omega = (f\eta'+df)\wedge\omega = 0.$$